# Swift: How to get date and time to update continuously?

Tags: swift

I've been working on getting the date and time to show up in my app like this by following tutorials:

```
let now = Date()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, yyyy"
DateLabel.text = formatter.string(from: now)

let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current
let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
let hourString = String(hour)
let minutesString = String(minutes)
TimeLabel.text = hourString + ":" + minutesString
```

But when I run the app on the simulator, the time doesn't change as the time on the phone changes. How do I make sure it does that?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to create and schedule a  timer and use it's method to update your label. Look for `Timer` tutorials there are ton of them !

Answer (score 2):

the main problem is that you are setting the text once and never updating it, the way I think it could work is to set the text every minute if you want to display only hour:minute or every second if you want hour:minute:second.

Setting the text every minute require an object called Timer, you can use it like this:

```
//timeInterval: 60 because you want to change every minute or 60 seconds
//selector: #selector(yourFunction)
//repeats: true so it will run until you stop it.
let everyMinuteTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60, target: self, 
selector: #selector(updateLabel), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func updateLabel() {
    let date = Date()
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
    let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
    let hourString = String(hour)
    let minutesString = String(minutes)
    TimeLabel.text = hourString + ":" + minutesString
}
```

Comment: Or just use block in schedulerTimer to reduce @objc functions. Also, better use DateFormatter with passed format for cleaner code

Comment: @PauliusVindzigelskis Even better, use a date formatter with a style instead of a fixed format.

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing simple knowledge how apps (or any software in that matter) work. There is continuous cycle every 30 ms (up to 60 ms ) on main thread which checks for any UI updates. As You call your code only once (probably on view loading), it is updated only once. to update continuously, you need to set up something like a timer for some interval (like minute or second, depending how your clock looks like) and run label updates passing new values gotten from recreated date or just increase a number yourself to get rid of overhaul.